# Show place of birth of birth/death/marriage with database traditional

Tags: genealogytree

Is there any way to display the place of birth/death/marriage in genealogytree with the template set to database traditional?

Demo:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}


\begin{document}

    \begin{genealogypicture}[
        template=database traditional,
        database format=full,
        place text={\newline}{},
        date format=dd.mm.yyyy,
        list separators={\par}{ }{}{}
    ]
        sandclock{
          child[id=GauaOsth1805]{
            p[id=OsthJoha1780]{
              female,
              name={\pref{Johanna} Elisabeth Rosina \surn{Osthoff}},
              birth={1780-05-08}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              marriage={1805-10-09}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1809-10-11}{G\"mottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              comment={ASDF},
          }
            g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
              male,
              name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker}
    
          }
            c[id=GauxCarl1806]{
              male,
              name={\pref{Carl} Joseph \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1806-08-21}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1873-07-04}{Hannover (Niedersachsen)},
          }
            c[id=GauxWilh1808]{
              female,
              name={\pref{Wilhelmina} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1808-02-29}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1840-08-12}{T\"ubingen (Baden-W\"urttemberg)},
          }
            c[id=GauxLudw1809]{
              male,
              name={\pref{Ludwig} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1809-09-10}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1810-03-01}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
          }
    }
    
}
    \end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 12.14 of the manual indicates that "Using this [database traditional] template, a sober black-and-white drawing with only **short** information is created." (emphasis added).

Therefore, rather than trying to enhance the data in the database traditional setting, I opted instead to change the node format of the default template.

I looked into the package file `gtrlib.templates.code.tex` to see how box structure was defined and copied some of that code.  In essence, I added `box clear` and `box={}` specifications, I removed the `template=database traditional` setting, and added a `processing=database` setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

    \begin{genealogypicture}[
% ADD BOX SPECIFICATION
    box clear,
    box={blanker,
      top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
      fit basedim=7pt,
      halign=flush center,
      fontupper=\sffamily,
      before upper={\parskip 0.15\tcbfitdim plus 0pt minus 0pt},
%      gtrnodealign
    },
        processing=database,%  <--ADD THIS
%        template=database traditional,% <--REMOVE THIS
        database format=full,
        place text={\newline}{},
        date format=dd.mm.yyyy,
        list separators={\par}{ }{}{}
    ]
        sandclock{
          child[id=GauaOsth1805]{
            p[id=OsthJoha1780]{
              female,
              name={\pref{Johanna} Elisabeth Rosina \surn{Osthoff}},
              birth={1780-05-08}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              marriage={1805-10-09}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1809-10-11}{G\"mottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              comment={ASDF},
          }
            g[id=GauxCarl1777]{
              male,
              name={Johann \pref{Carl Friedrich} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1777-04-30}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1855-02-23}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              profession={Mathematiker, Astronom, Geod\"at und Physiker}
    
          }
            c[id=GauxCarl1806]{
              male,
              name={\pref{Carl} Joseph \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1806-08-21}{Braunschweig (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1873-07-04}{Hannover (Niedersachsen)},
          }
            c[id=GauxWilh1808]{
              female,
              name={\pref{Wilhelmina} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1808-02-29}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1840-08-12}{T\"ubingen (Baden-W\"urttemberg)},
          }
            c[id=GauxLudw1809]{
              male,
              name={\pref{Ludwig} \surn{Gau\ss{}}},
              birth={1809-09-10}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
              death={1810-03-01}{G\"ottingen (Niedersachsen)},
          }
    }
    
}
    \end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for that answer! It works on the given dataset. However, if I use the child construct it creates huge spaces between nodes. Moreover, the lines are red and not as nicely rounded anymore... I adjusted my code to reflect my child construct

Comment: @Kalaschnik I'm sorry, my understanding of this package is at the beginner level.  However, if you go the same package file referenced in my answer (`gtrlib.templates.code.tex`), and explore that file, you will find that connecting lines are defined by the `edge` specifier.  For the "database traditional" template, it uses `edges={rounded=1mm,
      foreground={black,line width=0.3mm},
      background={white,line width=0.8mm}
    },` which could be added to your options.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out. It helps a lot to temporarily disable `blanker`. To make the boxes auto-height I used the `natural height` option. From the docs: >Using the option natural height, the height of a node box can be freely adapted to its content. Thanks for your help!